# Apache ODE, BPEL, Invoke RESTful API

Tags: bpel, restful-architecture, orchestration, apache-ode

Apache ODE documentation seems to support this i.e. invoking/orchestrating RESTFul APIs. 
No examples sources available on their site and even after trying hard on Google couldn't find anything useful.

Can someone help me to find a direction?

I'm using latest Apache ODE distribution with Eclipse BPEL designer.

We have a large SET of RESTFul APIs that provides the core interface to our business processes entirely. BPEL seems to be good Orchestration/Workflow programming solution but without the RESTFul API support out of the box I'm almost giving up on it.

I must be missing something here. Please suggest.

Comment: did you use Apache ODE finally? If not, which orchestration engine did you switch to?

Comment: @vanto, I didn't find any free BPEL designer supporting Apache ODE's WSDL 1.1 extension for REST. Do you know any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample is compliant with ws-BPEL 2.0 standard, we have tested only on wso2 bps, you'll be able to run it on ODE with minimal changes to the process. https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/products/bps/3.0.0/modules/samples/product/src/main/resources/bpel/2.0/TestRESTProcess